# Scala from command line RichInt NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: scala

I am new to Scala. Could you help me with a problem I am having when executing a Scala class from the command line.

Executing the code below in Eclipse I get the expected result, i.e. "hello" printed 10 times. However, when I execute from the command line, using **scala testArray** from the directory containing the file testArray.class then I get an exception

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/runtime/RichInt$
        at TestArray$.main(TestArray.scala:3)
        at TestArray.main(TestArray.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
...
```

I have a Windows XP machine, with Java 1.6 installed. The Scala bin directory is included in the PATH and the Scala directory is set as SCALA_HOME. I am using Scala 2.9.2.

The complete source:

```
object TestArray {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    var index: Int = 10

    for (index <- 0 until 10) {
      println("hello")
    }    
  }  
}
```

Comment: Have you restarted the console session after setting the environment variables? Windows don't updates those when you change any of the variables. Btw this is definitely a classpath issue.

Comment: Note: The line `var index: Int = 10` is not necessary; remove it from your code.

Comment: I did restart the command line and can see the environment variables are set OK using SET for example SCALA_HOME is set to c:\scala-2.9.2. The scala command I am using picks up Scala.bat included in the installation bin directory which is in the PATH, and I have not tampered with it.

Comment: It is strange that when the interpreter is started and I execute the following, I get no error, for (index <- 0 until 10) { println("hello")}

Comment: I cannot answer my question for another 5 hours. However I post here what I found which resolved the issue. After checking the source executed OK in the interpreter and then compiling outside Eclipse using scalac and also executing OK I gathered the Eclipse part must be at fault. Indeed I uninstalled scala from Eclipse and reinstalled from the nightly build and now the class the auto build produces executes with no problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking the source executed OK in the interpreter and then compiling outside Eclipse using scalac and also executing OK I gathered the Eclipse part must be at fault. Indeed I uninstalled scala from Eclipse and reinstalled from the nightly build and now the created class executes with no problem.